# using bootstrap containers for layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a layout that will resize properly, regardless of window size, resolution, etc.  Here is what I am trying to do:
[image: Layout of webpage]

```
    html, body {
       border: 0px;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       height:100%;
    }
    .container{
       height:100%;
       display:table;
       width: 80%; 
    }
   .row{    
      display: table-row;
   }
   @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .row .no-float {
         display: table-cell;
         float: none;
      }
   }
   .col-md-9 {
       background: #A28DFF;
       height:100%;    
    }
    .navbar {
       margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    </style>

<div class="container">
    <div class ="row " style="border:0px solid red;">
        <div class=" no-float" style="border:0px solid green; height:1px;">
            <!-- code for my nav bar -->
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-md-9 no-float" style="padding-top:50px">
            <!-- code for my content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, though, that it does not resize properly.  If the page becomes too small, the toolbar row and the content row split apart and do not resize with one another and do not stay together.  Can anyone help with tips on how to make this layout responsive to resizing?

Here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4qj7a3bh/13/

Comment: Can you make codepen, jsbin or something else so we can see your code in action ?

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle.  if you look at it, and resize the output window, you will see that the div's do not stay aligned.  thanks

Comment: If you downvoted or voted to close this post, can you explain why?  Doing so without comment does not help anyone.  thanks

Comment: For start you should never change bootstrap classes directly. Like what you are doing with .row for example !! Basically you made you are making mistakes with both `HTML` and `CSS`. I could make an example of how I would to it for bootstrap if you want ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 Yes, that would be helpful, thank you.  I am new to using Bootstrap and have gotten what I did from other posts.

Comment: I made answer for you hope you like it and if you have any follow up questions you can ask them in comments of my answer.

Comment: Doesn't look like any bootstrap call, according to your fiddle you are making up the container and row values yourself, this is not bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we concluded that you are not very experienced with bootstrap so I made this code for you. Here is the example of how to use bootstrap also you should explore their grid system so you can better understand code. Also you should really avoid targeting bootstrap classes directly unless it's absolutely necessary.

```
<div class="container mainC">
  <div id="toolbar" class="row text-center col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <h2>Toolbar section</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="row text-center col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <h2>Content section</h2>
  </div>
</div>

#toolbar {
  background: cyan;
}

#content {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Here is codepen so you can see code in action:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWaKxZ

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I am new to Bootstrap.  This looks good, but the only thing that is different is that I was trying to make the second div extend down to the bottom of the page.  Is there a way to do this without directly changing the Bootstrap classes?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes there are more ways to achieve this effect but as you add content it will extend by itself if you want you can use view height css property to achieve this, view height will always extend based on height of your window imagine it like something similar to percentages. Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eejzeY

Comment: Thank you.  this is what I was looking for!